# Убрать полный путь из строки ввода (cmd, windows)

Tags: windows, cmd

Существует ли настройка для cmd, чтобы в строке ввода не отображался полный путь, а к примеру последняя директория?

При работе бывает жутко мешает, когда путь занимает две строки и все это мельтешит перед глазами.

Как сейчас

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы, как то так примерно

```bash
C:\...\more longer and longer and longer name>
```

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/a-better-prompt-for-cmdexe-or-cool-prompt-environment-variables-and-a-nice-transparent-multiprompt

Comment: В папке путь до которой слишком длинный можно выполнить batch файл с таким содержимым ```cd %~d0%~ps0```